# Split comma separated string and store into variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I want to split a string and store every data to variable in C#.
How can I achieve that ?

My code is:

```
string name="John,Hutkins,Doe,San Francisco CA";
```

Output should be this:

```
string fname = "John";
string mname = "Hutkins";
string lname = "Doe";
string address= "San Francisco CA";
```

Comment: @HiteshKansagara Thanks, how about storing the data to variable ?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as simple as :

```
var results = name.Split(',');

if(results.Length != 4)
 throw new InvalidOperationException("Oh Noes!!!");

string fname = results[0];
string mname =  results[1];
string lname =  results[2];
string address=  results[3];
```

---

**Warning** the second you have a comma in your address, this is going to fail.

If this is a CSV file, consider using a dedicated CSV Parser, there are plenty

**Further reading**

[String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the case where it is better having a class

```
public class PersonalInfo 
{

    public FName { get; private set; }
    public LName { get; private set; }
    public MName { get; private set; }
    public Address { get; private set; }

    public PersonalInfo (string info)
    {
        string[] items = info.Split(',');
        FName = items [0];
        MName = items [1];
        LName = items [2];
        Address = items [3];

    }

    public override ToString()
    {
       // return $"{LName}, {FName} {MName}"; // vs 2017
       return string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", LName, FName, MName); // vs 2008
    }


}
```

Now you can actually use your objects in lists etc.

```
var pi = new PersonalInfo("John,Hutkins,Doe,San Francisco CA");
textBox1.Text = pi.FName;
. . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

If this string is from .csv file consider using an available csv parser.
Any way you can use this methid as well.

```
String [] results = name.Split(',');
```

In here your names will be stored in the results array. The index order will be the names order in the string starting with 0;
Like this

```
String address = results[3];
```

But there is a mistake here. Since you are using the comma to separate the values you cannot use Commas in the address which will be hard. Try using something like '|' od '*'.

Regards